# replace a column of factor data to a column of numeric data.

Tags: r

I have a column of factor data as "001:0 - 3.8979" and "002: 3.879-6.528". There are 61 of these in 10000 observations. I want replace these factors with the mean of each range, which I already calculated and saved in a text file as a column of numeric values. So, "001: 0-3.8939" becomes 1.9489 and so on.

How to do this quickly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without the need for an external file, this would do

```
ranges <- c("001:0 - 3.8979", "002: 3.879-6.528", "003: 7.528-10.356")

result <- sapply(ranges, function(r){
       # Split by ":" to remove the index, then take the second element
       # and split it by "-".
       values <- strsplit(strsplit(r, ":")[[1]][2], "-")
       # Return the mean (note you need to unlist the result of strsplit)
       mean(as.numeric(unlist(values)))
       })
```

Comment: +1 I was thinking more on the lines of `sapply(strsplit(ranges, ":|-"), function(x) mean(as.numeric(x[2:3])))`.